# How to use single quotes in console.log with multiple variables

Tags: typescript, tslint

If I write

```
console.log("entered values are "+A+" and "+B);
```

the `tsLint` complains that I should use `single quotes`. I found that if I use single quotes thatn I can't use multiple variables in single `console.log` i.e. I can't do

```
console.log('entered values are '+a+' and '+B);
```

Am I correct that I can't use multiple variables and single quotes if `tslint` warning about quotes is ON?

Comment: what is the actual tslint error with single quote?

Comment: you missed quotes on both cases, works with single or double quote if you do a correct syntax

Comment: You are not correct. Those two snippets should be functionally identical. https://tsplay.dev/aNn7vm

Comment: It's easier to spot missing tokens when you format code correctly. There's no difference between single and double quotes in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correct. I *guess* you have a type, like changing `A` for `a`.

```
"entered values are "+A+" and "+B
```

is equivalent to

```
'entered values are '+A+' and '+B`
```

is equivalent to

```
`entered values are ${A} and ${B}`
```